# why explicit operator std::string does not work

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, conversion-operator

I have a class which has a conversion operator for type std::string marked as explicit. Here is the class

```
class MyClass {

public:

// methods ...    

    explicit operator std::string() const {
        // convert to string ...
    }
}
```

Problem is when I use static_cast on a variable of type MyClass I get the error "No matching conversion for static_cast from 'MyClass' to 'std::string aka …" I seem to have the same problem when I define conversion operators for any custom type. Is the explicit modifier only defined for conversion to primitive types or is this another compiler bug.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/bO5g9O). SSCCE or it didn't happen.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `using namespace std`?  The shame.

Comment: Compiles and runs fine using Clang 3.3.

Comment: @Yakk: ideone puts it in by default. I plead guilty of aggravated laziness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by updating to the latest version of LLVM, which fully supports all C++11 features.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class MyClass {

public:

// methods ...    

    explicit operator std::string() const { 
        return "Hello World";
    }
};


int main() 
{
    MyClass obj;

    std::cout << static_cast<std::string>( obj )  << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
Hello World
```

Comment: Unfortunately it appears either my compiler does not support this feature for non-primitive types or this is just another one of its bugs. I get an error that no conversion exists when I attempt to static_cast it.

Comment: @ALXGTV You shoud provide a similar example that can be compiled.

Comment: What does compile is when I define explicit conversion operators for primitive types such as int and bool, then static_cast works as expected, however if I use a compound such as string, the cast only works if the operator is not marked as explicit.

Comment: @ALXGTV Show a ready to use simple program that demonstrates the problem.